# A pirate always goes right (R)?

Tags: meaning, word-usage, jokes

I heard about a conversation goes like

> A: In this stage I can only go R (right), which makes a?
>   B: Conservative?
>   A: A pirate.
>   B: Oh, that makes more sense.

I understand that conservative is also referred to as the right wing. But I don't get the pirate punch.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One of the ways people [talk like a pirate](http://talklikeapirate.com/piratehome.html) is to use the exclamation "Arrr!", which is pronounced the same way the letter R is pronounced.

There is an interesting article, [Arrr, Matey! The Origins of the Pirate Accent](http://dialectblog.com/2011/05/24/pirate-accent/), that theorizes the popular "pirate accent" is *crude imitation of the slightly similar West Country English*. It is just a theory, but I thought it was interesting.